# Fortify Sql Injection for Oracle

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, sql-injection, fortify

When I scan my project with fortify static code analyzer it finds Sql Injection results.

At Recommendations window fortify says : "The root cause of a SQL injection vulnerability is the ability of an attacker to change context in the SQL query, causing a value that the programmer intended to be interpreted as data to be interpreted as a command instead. When a SQL query is constructed, the programmer knows what should be interpreted as part of the command and what should be interpreted as data. Parameterized SQL statements can enforce this behavior by disallowing data-directed context changes and preventing nearly all SQL injection attacks. Parameterized SQL statements are constructed using strings of regular SQL, but when user-supplied data needs to be included, they create bind parameters, which are placeholders for data that is subsequently inserted. Bind parameters allow the program to explicitly specify to the database what should be treated as a command and what should be treated as data. When the program is ready to execute a statement, it specifies to the database the runtime values to use for the value of each of the bind parameters, without the risk of the data being interpreted as commands."

Look my code please. I am already using Parameterized SQL statements. So what is the problem? What am I missing?

**Summary of my code;**

```
Dim stateid As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Item("stateid"))
Dim colArgs As COLLECTIONS.ParamterCollection
colArgs = New COLLECTIONS.ParamterCollection
colArgs.Add(DATA.DataPreps.PrepStringForDB(stateid ))

Dim sSQL As String  = "SELECT * FROM STATE WHERE N_STATE_ID = :P"

PrepareSQL(sSQL, colArgs, objDBConfigObject)

Dim objCommand  As OracleCommand = new OracleCommand(sSQL, connection)

objCommand.CommandTimeout = m_nConnectionTimeout

For Each objArgument In colArgs
                        objParam = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter(":P" & CStr(nInArgIndex), objArgument.enOracleType)
                        objParam.Value = objArgument.varValue
                        objCommand.Parameters.Add(objParam)

                        nInArgIndex += 1

                        objArgument = Nothing
                        objParam = Nothing

                    Next

objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
objDataAdapter = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter(objCommand)
nRecordsAffected = objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet)
```

Comment: Try removing the single quotes around ':P' and see if that changes the result?

Comment: This is my mistake I wrote worng here. There are no quotes. I edited code

Comment: Are you sure you get the warning for this part of your code? Could there be other code in your project that isn't using a parametrised query? I don't know if the tool you're using includes easily understandable location information, but if not, you should be able to easily check by removing the parts of your code that you have checked to be safe (you use a VCS, right?) and re-running the analysis.

Comment: This is summary of my code actually project is very big and layered application. Fortify says "the method OracleServerExecuteQuery() invokes a SQL query built using input coming from an untrusted source.  This call could allow an attacker to modify the statement's meaning or to execute arbitrary SQL commands.
"

Answer (score 0):

You can use DBMS_ASSERT to validate all user inputs.Read this

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_assert.htm#BABIEIFE

Answer (score 0):

Parameterized queries are not a magic bullet.  I would add a few things:

1. objParam.OracleDbType = Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.VarChar (this is the db column data type)
2. Ensure you are doing input validation to defang any dangerous SQLi characters.
3. Perform some sanity checking on arguments being passed.  For example, how many max characters should the string stateid be?